# Iterating through repetitive blocks of tags with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```html
<block data-id="1234">
  <taga>New York</taga>
  <tagb>Yankees</tagb>
</block>
<block data-id="5678">
  <taga>Montreal</taga>
  <tagb>Expos</tagb>
</block>
<block data-id="2468">
  <taga>Boston</taga>
  <tagb>Red Sox</tagb>
</block>
```

Assuming I have the HTML above - Buried amongst some other HTML.

My approach to getting the data with Python and Selenium is:

```
teams = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//block")
for team in teams:
    print (team.get_attribute("data-id")
```

What is the right way to reference `<taga>` and `<tagb>` from the "team" element?
Instinctively I would try an xpath using the team like:

```
print(team.find_element("xpath", "//taga").text)
print(team.find_element("xpath", "//tagb").text)
```

but of course these xpath are absolute in the document, and not relative to the `<block>` I have referenced in "team"

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use **"."** for relative path.
Here is the corrected code:

```
print(team.find_element("xpath", ".//taga").text)
print(team.find_element("xpath", ".//tagb").text)
```